# RegEx : remove <img which src attribute is empty

Tags: php, regex

i want a regex pattern to remove images which src attribute is empty, for example :

```
$html = '<img src="adasas.jpg" /><br />asasas<br />sdfsdf<br /><img title="asa" src="" />';
```

or

```
$html = '<img src="adasas.jpg" /><br />asasas<br />sdfsdf<br /><a href="adafgag"><img title="asa" src="" /></a>';
```

if this `<img` exist between `<a>` tag, i want also remove all ( `<a` and `<img` ) .

I Tested below code, but it removed all of $html

```
echo preg_replace( '!(<a([^>]+)>)?<img(.*?)src=""([^>]+)>(</a>)?!si' , '' , $html );
```

Can anybody help to me ?

thanks in advance

Comment: It is not recommended to process html with regex. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) question.

Comment: @Ikke: I was about to link to the same question...

Comment: that's true, but i want this for my portal to remove fake images, i think for this, XML Parser is not needed, because i only want this ! can you help me to solve this by regex ?

Comment: @Boldwyn: It is THE question that gets linked, when a HTML+RegEx question is posted. LOL :D

Comment: The problem is it's very hard to get it right, and chance is that you miss an edge case and your regex fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is likely that the generic `.*?` matched too much. Rather use `[^>]*` like in the other parts of the pattern:

```
'!(<a\s[^>]+>)?<img([^>]+)src=""([^>]*)>(</a>)?!i'
```

Comment: worked great, tnx for regex, only problem i come across is malformed img tags like '<img src="some_url" title=">' but that is the case that I can ignore :)